# Get Mat object from Camera frame Android for OpenCV

Tags: android, sockets, opencv, mat

I am developing an android application based on Tutorial 2 given by OpenCV4Android. What I want to achieve is to get the Mat object of the camera frame when I touch the phone's screen (`onTouch()`). I want to modify the code such that I store the image as Mat instead of a jpeg file on the phone's memory. The Mat will then go under further processing.

Do I need to involve the `onCameraFrame()` function?
Any guidance will be much appreciated. I am very new to Android developing and OpenCV as well.

Note: I am using Android version 4.2.2 and OpenCV2.4.8.

**Edit:**

After editing `onTouch()` and `onCameraFrame()` functions these are the code snippets:

```
public Mat onCameraFrame(CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {

        Mat img = inputFrame.rgba();

        if(touched) {
            int imgsize = (int) (img.total()*img.channels());
            byte[] data = new byte[imgsize];
            img.get(0,0,data);
            int col = img.cols();
            int row = img.rows();
            Toast.makeText(this, "size:"+imgsize+" row:"+row+" col:"+col, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            StartSocket(row, col, imgsize, data);

            touched = false;
        }

        return img;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        Log.i(TAG,"onTouch event"); 
        touched = true;
        return true;
    }
```

What I did is basically convert the Mat object into a `ByteArray` called `data[]` and send it to a server through a socket along with other information. The socket works fine as a separate project when i try to send text files, so I believe there is nothing wrong with it.

And I don't have the `LogCat` since I am running the app directly on my device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want to process images from the camera, yes, you'll need the onCameraFrame() method, as it provides your image

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity implements CvCameraViewListener2,OnTouchListener {
    boolean touched=false;
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
         touched = true;
         return true;
    }
    public Mat onCameraFrame(CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {
        Mat rgba = inputFrame.rgba();
        if ( touched ) {
            // do some processing on rgba Mat
            touched = false;
        }
        return rgba;
    }
}
```

Comment: Help appreciated. I tried your method but the application stops unexpectedly the moment I touch the phone's screen.

Comment: you'll need to re-edit your question with the code you're using, and the logcat output, too.

Comment: I have the same issue. I don't really want to use onCameraFrame because I'm just going to need a frame only when user clicks a button. I don't want to be using camera all the time, but I'm going to need camera frames as Mat to process them. Any help?

Comment: @Brackets so you can just make the "default" camera app send you the taken picture with: `Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE); startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE/*=something...like...100*/);`
Then, in: '@Override protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)', You can get the take picture with: `mPhoto = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");`. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the solution to the problem. Ofcourse I wouldn't have done it without @berak help. From `LogCat` I found out that the failure was because of an issue with the threads. So I moved the following lines from `onTouch()` to `StartSocket()` function:

```
int imgsize = (int) (img.total()*img.channels());
            byte[] data = new byte[imgsize];
            img.get(0,0,data);
            int col = img.cols();
            int row = img.rows();
            Toast.makeText(this, "size:"+imgsize+" row:"+row+" col:"+col, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

I will put the relevant code snippet here so that others get use of it.

```
public class Tutorial3Activity extends Activity implements CvCameraViewListener2, OnTouchListener {

    static TextView msgReceived;
    String serverMsg = "";

    boolean touched = false;

    public Mat onCameraFrame(CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {

        Mat image = inputFrame.rgba();

        if(touched) {
            StartSocket(image); 
            touched = false;
        }

        return image;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        Log.i(TAG,"onTouch event"); 
        touched = true;

        return true;
    }

    private void StartSocket(final Mat img) {
        Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable(){

            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    final int imgsize = (int) (img.total()*img.channels());
                    byte[] data = new byte[imgsize];
                    img.get(0,0,data);
                    final int col = img.cols();
                    final int row = img.rows();

                    mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "size:"+imgsize+" row:"+row+" col:"+col, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });

                    //--- SEND IMAGE TO SERVER ---//
                    Socket s = new Socket ("192.168.1.25", 6000);

                    DataOutputStream dout = new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
                    dout.writeInt(col);
                    dout.writeInt(row);
                    dout.writeInt(imgsize);
                    dout.write(data);

                    mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Dout written", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });

                    dout.flush();
                                        dout.close();
                    s.close(); //close socket

                    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });

            t.start();
    }
```