# Android OpenCV Can't Detect Circles

Tags: android, opencv, feature-detection

Currently I'm developing android app to detect circles in camera view. I'm new to OpenCV and right now I'm trying to detect circles in Image not Camera for starters. I have written this code:

```
Bitmap photo = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), 
        R.drawable.circle);

Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "It works!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
Mat imgSource = new Mat(), imgCirclesOut = new Mat();

Utils.bitmapToMat(photo , imgSource);

Imgproc.cvtColor(imgSource, imgSource, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
Imgproc.GaussianBlur( imgSource, imgSource, new Size(9, 9), 2, 2 );
Imgproc.HoughCircles( imgSource, imgCirclesOut, Imgproc.CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, imgSource.rows()/8, 200, 100, 0, 0 );

float circle[] = new float[3];

for (int i = 0; i < imgCirclesOut.cols(); i++)
{
        imgCirclesOut.get(0, i, circle);
    org.opencv.core.Point center = new org.opencv.core.Point();
    center.x = circle[0];
    center.y = circle[1];
    Core.circle(imgSource, center, (int) circle[2], new Scalar(0,0,255), 5);
    }
    Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(photo.getWidth(), photo.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

    Utils.matToBitmap(imgSource, bmp);




image.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

That works when I press a button. According to all questions, tutorials and such that I checked this should work and detect my circle, but all it does is only process my image to grayscale. Here's how it looks in my app:

[image: Before click] [image: After click]

Help.

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://answers.opencv.org/question/24958/circle-detection-opencv-android/)?

Comment: No, I didn't. Thanks. I'll look into it and tell you about the results

Comment: Ok. Here's my MainActivity. There are three questions in the end that I can't solve. Overall - the thread was very useful. Thanks!

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23723553/3062311) should explain more

Comment: So if I want to do it without touch I should use this:  public Mat onCameraFrame(CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {
        Mat rgba = inputFrame.rgba();
      //my code here
        return rgba;
    }

Comment: Basically the code from the link just without if statement. And what about processingFrame? 2nd and 3d questions?

Comment: processingFrame is the convertion from rgba to gray of the current frame. Yes, it should be a Mat. As you can see there, processingFrame is one channel (gray scale), so you cannot draw a colored circle on a single channel Mat. For displaying the circle, you need to draw teh circle on the frame you display.

Comment: So, I've rewritten MainActivity.java using those 2 links of yours. I tried to launch my app. But all I get is black screen. I added Camera permission in Manifest. What I forgot to do then?

Comment: So it seems that you are a beginner too, I think that these two links ([1](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/android_binary_package/O4A_SDK.html) [2](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/android_binary_package/dev_with_OCV_on_Android.html#dev-with-ocv-on-android)) will clarify it. Start with the first basic thing then if it works try to find the problem in your code

Comment: I did as you told and simplified the task for starters. Now I'm trying to get drawable convert it to bitmap and process it with OpenCV and then return it in ImageView. I've updated MainActivity. Right now I get this [error](https://www.dropbox.com/s/1i30ambzzg9rvkt/img.png?dl=0). I also in Activity narrowed down everything to the source it's Mat. In fact error comes up when I create Mat. I've read that you cannot use OpenCV in OnCreate because it has not yet been loaded. Is that's why I get this?

Comment: yes, that's exactly the reason for your error. you need the opencvmanager code to load the opencv native so's.

Comment: Hm. Well I have OpenCVManager installed on the phone. I also moved The function from onCreate. You can see MainActivity. But it still gives me the error.

Comment: **bump this question**

Answer (score 2):

you need to load the opencv native so's , before you can execute any opencv related code:

```
private BaseLoaderCallback  mLoaderCallback = new BaseLoaderCallback(this) {
    @Override
    public void onManagerConnected(int status) {
        switch (status) {
            case LoaderCallbackInterface.SUCCESS:
            {
                Log.i(TAG, "OpenCV loaded successfully");
                // either call your opencv code from **here**
                // or from onCameraViewStarted(). either way, you will have 
                // to wait, until this thing finished (async!)
            } break;
            default:
            {
                super.onManagerConnected(status);
            } break;
        }
    }
};


@Override
public void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();
    OpenCVLoader.initAsync(OpenCVLoader.OPENCV_VERSION_2_4_3, this, mLoaderCallback);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works great! Now I'm working on getting image processed. Here's what I [get](https://photos-6.dropbox.com/t/2/AAAWMXmDQJ_EPTqqSdHIYtEvnEIjicDjJW7DjPN8ric0IQ/12/270666750/png/32x32/1/_/1/2/img.png/CP6XiIEBIAEgAiADIAQgBSAGIAcoAQ/PZwaWQi6ihaSsz0IW861wzEaaonPHUchKOkHU-GEoko?size=1280x960&size_mode=2). Error highlighted. And it happens with first Imgproc.  I checked - I have all imports, Manager Works correctly, everything looks fine. Where's the problem then?

Comment: please *paste the text* of your error here, i won't look at your drobox

Comment: It's a direct link to image, not dropbox(I couldn't do the same earlier since my comment was already too long). Here's the text of the error: at org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc,cvtColor(Imgproc.java:4244)-  android Runtime Error

Comment: Anybody know's why this error keeps popping up? I'm trying all sorts of things, but not helping.